# C# Winform COM interop and Threading

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, com, interop

I have been reading (again) a lot about COM interopability and threading. Well, now, I'm facing some trouble understanding the following scenario.

I have a COM Dll referenced in VS2008 named ComDbLib and by the VS2008 object browser I can see that it has a:

- public class ComDb2Class that inherit interfaces IComDb2, ComDb2,
  IComDb;
- public interface IComDb2 that inherit interface IComDb;
- public interface ComDb2 that inherit interface IComDb2;
- public interface IComDb;

Making a call from a MTA BGWorker thread to a method that creates a new object of ComDb2Class type (`ComDb2Class objectDb = new ComDb2Class();`) fails with the well known exception:

«Unable to cast COM object of type 'ComDb2Class' to interface type 'IComDb2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 'XXXXXXXX' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).».

I need the BGWorker so it must be part of the solution.

Making a call to the same method but from an STA thread there is not an exception. Anyway I want to avoid this approach because i would need to make a new Thread each time i want to call this method (there will be numerous calls to the method and these calls are not localized in a single place in the aplication but are dispersed through it), this approach would be time costly.

Now the part that intrigues me is that if you invoke the method that creates an object of type (`IComDb objectDb = new ComDb2Class();`) from a MTA BGWorker thread it doesn't give any exception!

I can't understand it, for me it would make sense that the exception would arise from any calls from a MTA Thread, because the COM would a STA and could only be invoked in a STA Thread.

Geezz i'm getting lost here :s can you explain to me why the class constructor failed in the first approach and not in the last??

Comment: can you change the BGWorker thread to STA?

Comment: @pstrjds no, the BGWorker threads are MTA i can get a new STA Thread inside BGWorker and delegate the method call to it, but as said this has a overhead that i don't want to have...

Comment: are you connecting to IBM's DB2? If so, why not use the DB2 .Net client libraries instead of the COM interface?

Comment: @pstrjds No it's not IBM's DB2.